# Get the category of a given sentence from a categorized corpus using NLTK

Tags: python, nltk, corpus

Using NLTK, I've created a categorized corpus of approximately 100k sentences split into 36 categories.

I can access the sentences of a particular category like this:

```
romantic_comedies_sents = (my_corpus.sents(categories='romantic_comedies'))
```

However, given a sentence in the form of a tokenized `list` such as `["You", "had", "me", "at", "hello"]` I'd like to efficiently identify the categories in which it occurs. Is there a fast way of doing this?

I've tried creating and using a dictionary with sentences as keys and categories as values, but creating this dictionary takes a long time on my computer (especially in comparison with NLTK's built in methods) and I was wondering if there's a better way of doing it, preferably using NLTK.

Ultimately I'm trying to end up with this structure for every sentence:

```
(["You", "had", "me", "at", "hello"], set("romantic_comedies"))
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NLTK's corpus reader's sents() function returns a list of lists. This is not a particularly efficient structure for looping through to create a dictionary mapping sentences to categories.

**The answer was to convert the sentences to tuples and the list of sentences to a set (I only needed distinct sentences).**

Once converted the loops used to create the dictionary mapping sentences to categories were finished in 18 seconds rather than taking all night.

Answer (score 0):

A [prefix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) is an efficient way of creating a dictionary that maps sequences onto values. Below is a simple implementation:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, word=None):
        self.word = word
        self.children = {}
        self.categories = set()

    def add(self, sentence, category):
        if len(sentence):
            word = sentence[0]
            sentence = sentence[1:]
            if word not in self.children:
                self.children[word] = Node(word);
            self.children[word].add(sentence, category)
        else:
            self.categories.add(category)

    def find(self, sentence):
        if len(sentence):
            word = sentence[0]
            sentence = sentence[1:]
            if word not in self.children:
                return []
            return self.children[word].find(sentence)
        else:
            return self.categories

class PrefixTree(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Node()

    def add(self, sentence, category):
        self.root.add(sentence, category)

    def find(self, sentence):
        return self.root.find(sentence)
```

Use it like this:

```
def main():
    tree = PrefixTree()
    sentence = ["You", "had", "me", "at", "hello"]
    tree.add(sentence, "romantic_comedies")
    print tree.find(sentence)
```

Output:

```
set(['romantic_comedies'])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for replying. I'll accept your answer tomorrow once checked, unless someone knows of a way to do this within NLTK!

Comment: Thanks again for your contribution, but it turned out the problem lay elsewhere.